# Hundreds of Apache SSHD clients leave hundreds of OpenSSH daemon processes running

Tags: jsch, openssh, apache-mina, sshd

I use a the Apache SSHD java library's client to serve files over HTTP that are read via SSH. The concept app works great.

But when I want to read hundreds of files serially (e.g. to display images in a gallery) I run into scalability problems: my server ends up with hundreds of OpenSSH daemon processes:

- under my username as `/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server` and
- `sshd:username@notty`, and
- under root as `sshd: username [priv]`

which causes my server to run out of memory and my server to crash.

I don't think this is a bug in OpenSSH (I'm using `OpenSSH_5.9p1`), but how I'm using the Apache SSHD client.

Here is the code I run every time I serve a file:

```java
SshClient client = SshClient.setUpDefaultClient();
client.getProperties().put(ClientFactoryManager.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL, "50000");
client.start();
session = client.connect("username", "server", 22).await().getSession();
session.addPasswordIdentity("password");
session.auth().await();
SftpClient sftp = session.createSftpClient();
// Create an HTTP response from an sftp channel stream
```

Which of the following, if any, do I need to make hundreds of JSch client requests?

1. Close/stop my session and/or client after each request? (the
   terminology here is so generic yet the functionality is so precise
   that I may have wrong understanding of each component)?
2. Client pooling?
3. Server configuration to limit the number of daemon threads?
4. Reduce the timeout (on the client or on the server)?

Any insight, specific or general, would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely must disconnect your SSH/SFTP session after your are done with it:

```java
client.stop();
```

Client pooling is not bad idea, but you do it only after disconnecting does not help.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The reason I left the connection open was that I wanted to reuse connections and avoid authenticating each time. Obviously I messed that up, but what is the right way to avoid redundant connecting/disconnecting?

Comment: Well that's not a question for JSch. But rather about keeping persistent objects in webserver across different HTTP requests. But for that we need to know what web server/environment you are using. It's basically a completely different question. And I'm pretty sure it's answered on SO already.

Comment: Okay great, thanks for straightening out my confusion. I'm marking this as correct for now but haven't yet tried it out (I need to find the Apache SSHD client code that corresponds to JSCH's `session.disconnect()`).

Comment: It's `client.stop()` in Apache SSH. I actually do not see how Apache SSH is related to JSch.

Comment: Thanks. I thought Apache Mina's SSHD component used Jsch under the hood, but it looks like I'm mistaken (https://github.com/apache/mina-sshd/blob/master/sshd-core/pom.xml). Lucky for me, I'm not too fond of JSCH anyway.

Comment: I can confirm that this works. I don't end up with hundreds of sshd processes. It's also fast to serve the files because the server has more free memory. I'm just intellectually unsatisfied that I'm not (yet) reusing connections. But I'll cross that bridge more carefully next time around. Thanks again.